# how to sort the vertex according to degree in igraph layout_in_circle

Tags: r, igraph, graph-visualization

When I visualize the network using igraph:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(v1=sample(letters[1:10],20,replace=TRUE),
                  v2=sample(letters[1:10],20,replace=TRUE))
g<-graph.data.frame(dt1, directed=F)
plot(g,layout=layout_in_circle)
```

[image]

I want to plot the vertex in the order with degree decreasing. How can I do that?
I have using `degree(g)` to get the degree information. However, the order of the nodes plotted is according to the inner order in the *g* object, i.e. the index number. If you assign the name of the nodes using `V(g)$name <-`, the name changed, but the ID to the name relation also changed.

Comment: count the vertices degree in the igraph object. Create the attributes needed as nodes or edge list (should be mentioned in the manual). Approach a method to count how many times a node appears in the edge list. Could that help?

Comment: Hi @Rockbar, I have tried using _degree(g)_ to get the degree information. But how can I reorder the index of the vertex IDs?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a "as.edge.list" functions. From that approach a counting algorithm I think

Comment: Thank you Rockbar, I have caught your idea, you mean to get the degree information of every vertex. I have got this data using `degree()` function. However, how can I plot the graph with the vertex sorted by degree? Currently, the default order of the vertex is determined when you construct the network.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the documentation of `layout_in_circle` (i.e. type `help(layout_in_circle)` in R); it says that the function has an argument named `order`:

> *order*: The vertices to place on the circle, in the order of their
>             desired placement. Vertices that are not included here will
>             be placed at (0,0)

So, all you need to do is to create an order vector based on the degrees of the vertices using the `order()` function in R and then pass that to the `order` argument to create the layout:

```
> layout <- layout_in_circle(g, order=order(degree(g)))
> plot(g, layout=layout)
```